# file path in hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I want to read the file from the Hadoop File System.

In order to achieve the correct path of the file, I need host name and port address of the `hdfs`.

so finally my path of the file will look something like

```
Path path = new Path("hdfs://123.23.12.4344:9000/user/filename.txt")
```

Now I want to know to extract the HostName = "123.23.12.4344" & port: 9000?

Basically, I want to access the FileSystem on Amazon EMR but, when I use

```
 FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
```

I get

```
 
You possibly called FileSystem.get(conf) when you should have called FileSystem.get(uri, conf) to obtain a file system supporting your path
```

So I decided to use URI. (I have to use URI) but I am not sure how to access the URI.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use either of the two ways to solve your error.

**1.**

```
String infile = "file.txt";
Path ofile = new Path(infile);
FileSystem fs = ofile.getFileSystem(getConf());
```

**2.**

```
Configuration conf = getConf();
System.out.println("fs.default.name : - " + conf.get("fs.default.name"));
// It prints uri  as : hdfs://10.214.15.165:9000 or something
String uri = conf.get("fs.default.name");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(uri,getConf());
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  It helped, can you explain why this is?

Comment: Hadoop has a FileSystem factory.  It creates the correct file system based on the URI scheme, and maybe the authority portion of the URI.  You can see if you were to open a file on file://, s3:// or hdfs:// you would need a different file system for each one.  That is why you need to include the URI

Comment: fs.default.name is deprecated, every reader of this question should use fs.defaultFS instead.