# using amazon s3 as input,output and to store intermediate results in EMR map reduce job

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I am trying to use Amazon s3 storage with EMR. However, when I currently run my code I get multiple errors like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This file system object (hdfs://10.254.37.109:9000)    does not support access to the request path 's3n://energydata/input/centers_200_10k_norm.csv' You possibly called FileSystem.get(conf) when you should have called FileSystem.get(uri, conf) to obtain a file system supporting your path.
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:384)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:129)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:154)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:429)
at edu.stanford.cs246.hw2.KMeans$CentroidMapper.setup(KMeans.java:112)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:771)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

In main I set my input and output paths like this and I put s3n://energydata/input/centers_200_10k_norm.csv in configuration CFILE that I retrieve in the mapper and reducer:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
conf.set(CFILE, inPath); //inPath in this case is s3n://energydata/input/centers_200_10k_norm.csv
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputDir));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputDir));
```

The specific example where the error above occurs in my mapper and reducer where I try to access CFILE (s3n://energydata/input/centers_200_10k_norm.csv). This is how I try to get the path:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
Path cFile = new Path(context.getConfiguration().get(CFILE));
DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(fs.open(cFile));  ---->Error
```

s3n://energydata/input/centers_200_10k_norm.csv is one of the input arguments to the program and when I launched my EMR job I specified my input and output directories to be s3n://energydata/input and s3n://energydata/output

I tried doing what was suggested in [file path in hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577767/file-path-in-hdfs) but I'm still getting the error. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try instead:

```
Path cFile = new Path(context.getConfiguration().get(CFILE));
FileSystem fs = cFile.getFileSystem(context.getConfiguration());
DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(fs.open(cFile));
```

Comment: thanks. I actually fixed it by using the following code: uriStr =  "s3n://energydata/output/";
URI uri = URI.create(uriStr);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(uri, context.getConfiguration()); 
Path cFile = new Path(context.getConfiguration().get(CFILE));DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(fs.open(cFile));

Comment: yeah - that's also a similar fix. the main thing was in the OP the filesystem handle was the default one. either Path.getFileSystem or FileSystem.get(path, conf) obtains the file system for the specific path

Answer (score 2):

thanks. I actually fixed it by using the following code:

```
String uriStr =  "s3n://energydata/centroid/";
URI uri = URI.create(uriStr);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(uri, context.getConfiguration());    
Path cFile = new Path(context.getConfiguration().get(CFILE));  
DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(fs.open(cFile));
```