# error whilst importing csv to hdfs in windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, hdfs

Hoping somebody could help, i've been trying to set up hadoop on windows, so far everything seems to be working but now I'm trying to import a csv file into hdfs.

I use the following code

hadoop fs -put c:\input\file.txt c:\output

but get the following error

-put: Pathname /c:/output from hdfs://localhost:9000/c:/output is not a valid DFS filename.
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -put [-f] [-p] [-l]  ...

I've been googling solutions but none seem to be quite the problem I have and I can't find a way around it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says c:/output is NOT a valid hdfs file name. 
A valid destination directory on hdfs would be /output
1. Create the destination directory on hdfs : hdfs dfs -mkdir /output 
 2. Put file on hdfs : hdfs dfs -put  /output

Comment: Great, this seems to work! Another question, what are the paths for the files now they are in the hdfs, if say I wanted to access them from eclipse?

Comment: To access the files from java this is useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577767/file-path-in-hdfs http://undercloud.org/2010/12/26/accessing-to-hdfs-with-java-interface/        http://www.mund-consulting.com/Blog/Posts/file-operations-in-HDFS-using-java.aspx  . Honest advice: please google a bit more about this stuff  :)